# roscd: command not found (in groovy 12.04)

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbash is installed but the following gives :

```
$ roscd
roscd: command not found
```

This initial command from the rosbash wiki page returns:

```
$ source ${ROS_ROOT}/tools/rosbash/rosbash
bash: /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/tools/rosbash/rosbash: No such file or directory
```

The version of the package is :

```
$ dpkg -s ros-groovy-rosbash
Package: ros-groovy-rosbash
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 131
Maintainer: Dirk Thomas <dthomas@osrfoundation.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.9.45-0precise-20130325-0832-+0000
Depends: ros-groovy-catkin
Description: Assorted shell commands for using ros with bash.
Homepage: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66913/roscd:-command-not-found-(in-groovy-12.04)/) by [jmainpri](https://answers.ros.org/users/4656/jmainpri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The comment on the rosbash wiki page was outdated. I have updated the wiki page.

The correct way is to source `/opt/ros/DISTRONAME/setup.bash` instead of the rosbash file. This will not only give you bash-specific completions but also the correct environment variable like ROS_ROOT, ROS_PACKAGE_PATH etc.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jmainpri](https://answers.ros.org/users/4656/jmainpri/) on 2013-07-09**:
It doesn't work for me.